# What shortcut for repeating inset plane?

Tags: shortcut

I'm a new. How to repeat inset mesh/plane couple of times like that:

[image]

https://www.dropbox.com/s/m6ltsz1szsmr62k/how%20repeat%20plane.gif?dl=0

Comment: [Shift-R] repeats the last operation. [I] inset, followed by that, will do it.

Comment: Thank you, Robin! it works